# How to initialize a class in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have begun adding `interfaces` to my angular app but the concept is new to my as I come from a Railsy world.  After creating a model in Rails, I could initialize the empty model with null values very easily:

```
Foo.new
```

where `Foo` is the model name.  In Angular I've created a typescript `interface`:

```
export interface Consultation {
  id?: number;
  submitted?: boolean;
  showed_up?: boolean;
  signed_up?: boolean;
}
```

I've also made a similar `class`:

```
export class ConsultationInit {
  constructor(
    id?: number,
    submitted?: boolean,
    showed_up?: boolean,
    signed_up?: boolean
  )
}
```

but I am a bit confused on how to initialize an empty `Consultation`.  This method seems very un-DRY.  I understand that the `interface` is the object `type` but if I am to create an instance of a `Consultation` do I need to supply params or can I call the equivalent of `Consultation.new`

Comment: Interfaces in typescript does **not** exist at runtime. You probably rather want to do something like: `export class ConsultationInit implements Consultation`. The "Consultation instance" you're talking about **cannot** exist, since `Consultation` is an interface, not a class. Finally, to create your instance, you should do: `new ConsultationInit()`. This will create an **empty** instance. Be aware (once again) that `interfaces` in typescript are FAR different from other languages.

Comment: Do I need to supply parameters when initializing?  I thought it would have to be `new ConsultationInit(null, null, null, null)` which is such a pain

Comment: No, you don't, since they are "nullable" (not really nullable, but they conceptually are).

Comment: when I call `new ConsultationInit(null, null, true, true)` it still says that the value is `undefined`.  Shouldn't the result be an object with those values?

Comment: No, you need to **fill** the values manually, or define them public or private: `export class ConsultationInit { constructor(public id?: number; public submitted?: boolean, public showed_up?: boolean, public signed_up?: boolean) {} }`, otherwise, you need to **declare** the class properties in the class definition, like **every other OOP language**.